# Changing Azure domain name and keep the .onmicrosoft.com

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to check if it is possible to change the tenant domain in Azure but also keep the .onmicrosoft.com. Let say I have a tenant with the name of labtest.onmicrosoft.com and I want to change it to mydomain.onmicrosoft.com. Is that possible?

I found a solution that says to create a different directory with the desired name and then send all the resource to the new directory. Has anyone tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not possible, you cannot edit your domain.